# Reverse-Engineering Memory Load Techniques?

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, ida

I am attempting to reverse engineer a game (with permission). I am using IDA Pro. The functions are `sub_xxxxx`, meaning that they are protected functions.

However, the strings that would be the names for the functions, when looking at the only cross-reference, are shown in the following manner:

```
__data:xxxxxxxx                 DCD aEcdh_compute_k     ; "ECDH_compute_key"
__data:xxxxxxxx                 DCB   0
__data:xxxxxxxx                 DCB 0x40
__data:xxxxxxxx                 DCB   12
__data:xxxxxxxx                 DCB 0x3B
```

Some of the numbers, including the DCBs are changed for the sake of safety (OCD)

I had attempted to use the `40 12 3B` to use as an offset. However, the offset brings me to the middle of a random `loc_xxxxx`, along with the others.

My question to you is, how would I go about finding where the actual function is? Is the offset from the top of the `.data` segment? Or is it from the actual declaring string itself?

I do not expect or require a full answer; obviously this may not have been encountered in the past, and I may not have given enough information needed. (If you need more information, please ask, thanks). Basically, I am asking, "What should I try next?", trying to find the most likely answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're ignoring the processors endianity, which is usually [*little endian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian).

Hhitting <kbd>D</kbd> two times (once to convert data representation from single byte to word and another to convert it from word to dword) will convert the data to a dword for you. Alternatively, you could also hit <kbd>O</kbd> to directly convert data representation to an offset (which is of size dword on most architectures)

This is most likely to show you offset to address `0x003b1240`, which is probably the address you were looking for.